# Como converter um objeto javascript para apresentação do usuário?

Tags: javascript, firebase

Preciso apresentar os resultados de uma consulta do firebase para o usuário.
Para realizar testes, debugar código manualmente e verificar condições, normalmente usamos alguma função como o console.log, alert, retornos json, array, etc, durante o desenvolvimento.
Porém em algum momento, os dados dessas consultas terão que ser apresentados na tela para o usuário, e a última coisa que queremos é que ele veja alguma árvore de estrutura de dados com chaves, colchetes, etc.

No meu caso específico, estou utilizando o firebase, e usando os códigos da documentação.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var db = firebase.firestore();

    var docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");

    docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
            console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
        } else {
            // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            console.log("No such document!");
        }
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });




    var citiesRef = db.collection("cities");

    var query = citiesRef.where("state", "==", "CA");

    </script>
```

A questão é como pego dados destes objetos (docRef e query) e apresento de forma amigável ao usuário.

Comment: Talvez algo como [JSONT](http://goessner.net/articles/jsont/) possa te ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem algumas bibliotecas especializadas nisso, dá uma olhada em: https://json2html.com

Há um novo recurso no Chrome que também pode ajudar, chamado console.table(), que exibe no console uma tabela estilizada com as informações

Comment: Fantástica essa solução! obg!

Deixar aqui o trecho do código para quem passar pelo mesmo problema:

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2html/1.2.0/json2html.min.js"></script>

var citiesRef = db.collection("cities");

var query = citiesRef.where("state", "==", "CA");


 var t = {'<>':'div','html':'${country} ${year}'};
            
        var d = [
            {
  "capital": false,
  "country": "USA",
  "name": "San Francisco",
  "population": 860000,
  "state": "CA"
}
        ];
            
        document.write( json2html.transform(d,t) );